# Bi clustering over multidimensional data in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Consider a case where we have `n` students, `m` subjects, and each subject has `q` tests grades. Now we are interested in determining the group of students who perform in a similar manner in some subjects. See below figure to understand it further (5 students, 5 subjects, and each subject has 5 test grades, shown as dots):
[image]

Based on these multidimensional test scores, how can we identify the similar groups?

My approach: I tried to use [bi-clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biclustering) in the [mixOmics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixOmics/mixOmics.pdf) `R` package, but I found that `cim` function in this package does not allow multidimensional data. Since there are `q` test grades (>1). Do we need to reduce the dimensions? If yes, how can we reduce these dimenisons before clustering.

Here is the dummy data

```
# 6 students, 7 subjects and 5 tests
df <- data.frame(rnorm(35,3,2),rnorm(35,3,2),rnorm(35,3,2),rnorm(35,3,2),rnorm(35,3,2),rnorm(35,3,2))
colnames(df) <- paste0("Std",1:6)
row.names(df) <- paste0(rep(paste0("sub",1:7),each=5),1:5)
```

Comment: Start basic: `heatmap(as.matrix(df))` will show you if what you're working with.

Comment: Ideally, the heat map axis should be  `students` and `subjects`, but it shows `students` and `student grades`. I believe there must be some package which will take care of multidimensional subject grades!

Comment: If those numbers with `sub` are two variables, you should store them as such, or maybe better the whole thing in an array so you can take slices.